# Ternary Operator and Twitter Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am working with Twitter Typeahead and all is going well so far. I am able to return the *availability*, *title*, *author* and *description* in the search suggestions. Now I am simply trying to add a css label (success/warning) to the text returned within the search bar but I'm not sure what syntax I need to use, for example;

If **available** `<span class="label label-success">available</span>`

If **unavailable** `<span class="label label-success">unavailable</span>`

The availability field in my json file returns 1 for available and 0 for unavailable. I have tried syntax such as the following but it doesn't work - it simply prints out the html;

```
available:  (available == 1) ? '<span class="label label-success">available</span>' : '<span class="label label-warning">unavailable</span>'
```

In my **typeahead.js** I use the following template to display results;

```
filter: function(list) {
  return $.map(list, function(book) { 
        return { 
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        available: book.available,
        description: book.description
        }; 
    });
}

...

$('.demo .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'title', 
  engine: Handlebars,
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no results found',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
       '<p>{{available}}</p> \n\ //this is the line I want to add the label-badge to
        <p>{{title}}</p> \n\
        <p>{{author}}</p> \n\
        <p>{{description}}</p>'
        ) 
  },
  engine: Handlebars,
  source: books.ttAdapter()  
});
```

Very new to JS here so any advice is appreciated. I can also provide more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Book javascript object that would contain the logic as follows:

```
var Book = function(data)
{
    self = this;
    self.title = data.title;
    self.author = data.author;
    self.available = data.available;        
    self.description = data.description;
    self.availableHtml = function()
    {
         return (self.available == 1) ? '<span class="label label-success">available</span>' : '<span class="label label-warning">unavailable</span>'   
    }
}
```

Then map it as follows:

```
filter: function(list) {
  return $.map(list, function(book) { 
        return new Book({ 
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        available: book.available,
        description: book.description
        }); 
    });
}
```

And change your handlebar compile to this:

```
suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
       '<p>{{{availableHtml}}}</p> \n\ //this is the line I want to add the label-badge to
        <p>{{title}}</p> \n\
        <p>{{author}}</p> \n\
        <p>{{description}}</p>'
        )
```

**Update**

I think the answer may have been simpler than I originally thought.

If you simply need to escape the html use three brackets i.e.

```
suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
   '<p>{{{available}}}</p> \n\ //this is the line I want to add the label-badge to
    <p>{{title}}</p> \n\
    <p>{{author}}</p> \n\
    <p>{{description}}</p>'
    )
```

Comment: Perfect @hutchonoid your update worked a treat. Why did I need to use three brackets?

Comment: @johnny_s Handlebars uses triple brackets to escape html encoding. I guess it is encoded as a safety precausion by default. Please accept the answer with the green tick. :)